# PM2-health : can i use pm2-health module for sending email alerts/notifications?

Tags: pm2

I have a nodejs application which runs on pm2 and I need to be able to send email notifications whenever a crash/ restart occurs. My idea is to monitor the application for crashes and trigger a mail action from pm2-health. The documentation of pm2-health module is  [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2-health)  but I'm unable to use it for sending email alerts. Can anyone explain how to use it for this purpose?

P.S: Also, it would be great if you could explain about SMTP configuration for gmail.(I have configured postfix to use gmail smtp according to [this](https://kifarunix.com/configure-postfix-to-use-gmail-smtp-on-ubuntu-18-04/) and it works fine for test gmail but doesn't work with pm2-health)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is how I could get pm2-health working with my Gmail account:

1. Install pm2-health module:

`pm2 install pm2-health`

2. Open PM2 module config file:

`vim ~/.pm2/module_conf.json`

3. Update it with the Gmail account’s SMTP parameters:

```
{
    "pm2-health": {
        "smtp": {
            "host": "smtp.gmail.com",
            "port": 465,
            "user": "EXAMPLE_sender@gmail.com",
            "password": "PASSWORD",
            "secure": true,
            "disabled": false
        },
        "mailTo": "NOTIFICATION_RECIPIENT_EMAIL_ADDRESS",
        "replyTo": "EXAMPLE_SENDER@gmail.com",
        "events": [
            "exit"
        ],
        "exceptions": true,
        "messages": true,
        "messageExcludeExps": [],
        "metric": {},
        "metricIntervalS": 60,
        "aliveTimeoutS": 300,
        "addLogs": false,
        "appsExcluded": [],
        "snapshot": {
            "url": "",
            "token": "",
            "auth": {
                "user": "",
                "password": ""
            },
            "disabled": false
        }
    },
    "module-db-v2": {
        "pm2-health": {}
    }
}
```

4. Save and close it
5. Restart pm2-health:

`pm2 restart pm2-health`

Test it by restarting one of your PM2-managed Node processes. You should receive an email about that event.

Comment: you saved my day

Comment: can I send the alert to multiple RECIPIENTS ?

Comment: @AnkitaBasu, Yes, Just add your emails in mailTo by separating them by a comma. https://github.com/pankleks/pm2-health#all-config-options

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying to use with 2FA enabled Gmail, you need to use an App Password. More information here: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833